Playing live DASH content with SCTE35 markers in Exoplayer - Android
I am playing a Live DASH content to exoplayer by passing the media URL.
The content is playing but when the SCTE35 marker is processing content is freezing for 3 or 4 frames and this 3 or 4 being skipped.
I am using media3 exoplayer version 1.4.1
Is this a know issue in exoplayer or is there any fixes for this?
Thanks in advance
